# Ubuntu 22.04 RDP Fails to connect if Auto Login is enabled

Tags: gnome, 22.04, rdp

On Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome and Wayland server (also tried X11) it is not possible to remote to the Gnome RDP when Auto Login is enabled. Even after re-starts.

Is there some sort of config I am missing?

Comment: To clarify, the machine you're connecting to has auto-login enabled, and the password in the RDP settings is blank?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Yes to both but now I seem to get the following error: The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer. I am not experienced with KeyRing but I imagine that this might be a security nightmare to auto unlock it upon login? Note that my machine is a gaming rig/personal dev/media server

Comment: I also store my own passwords in another application database, not in keyring itelf